# How will adbd and monkey runner affect the performance of the android device

Tags: android, adb, monkeyrunner

I am doing some performance testing of the device and want to use the adb and monkey runner to automate andorid UI*. The concern is the background process would affect the actual performance of the device.
Questions are:

Through what mechanism does monkey runner work?

How much the performance* will be affected by the services of adb and monkeyrunner running on the device?

*sending command via adb to run monkey runner and pull the logcat.
*hardware performance: cpu mem power

Comment: When you say adb services, do you mean like using debug logs that can be viewed through logcat?

Comment: I don't think so. Since they are talking about monkeyrunner I would assume that they are referring to using adb to send commands to the a device.

Answer (score 0):

The [MonkeyRunner intro page](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html) has a good description of how MonkeyRunner works. Based on my personal experience using MonkeyRunner shouldn't impact your app's performance, however MonkeyRunner itself can sometimes be slow, so I wouldn't ever use MonkeyRunner to measure my app's performance.

Comment: I'm talking more about hardware performance: cpu mem power. So you think they would be affected heavily?

Comment: Like I said, I don't think that actual performance of your app will be impacted. However, in general MonekyRunner itself is slow. So while your app may be preforming fine it may take MonkeyRunner sometime to execute commands.